# Eclipse plugin dev: Add actions / keyboard shortcut for Editor ToolBar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nodeclipse, enide

Inside [Eclipse Image Viewer plugin](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/quickimage) I want to add moving on arrow keys left <kbd><-</kbd> 
or right <kbd>-></kbd> to the next or previous image (in Fullsize mode)

[image]

`QuickImageEditor` uses `ToolBar` and `ToolItem`.

https://github.com/Nodeclipse/quickimage/blob/master/quickimage/src/nu/psnet/quickimage/editors/QuickImageEditor.java#L118-128

```
    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(compos, SWT.FLAT);
    toolBar.setLayoutData(toolbarData);


    previous = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.FLAT);
    previous.setToolTipText("Previous Image");
    previous.setImage(new Image(parent.getDisplay(), iconsdir + "previous.gif"));
    previous.setSelection(true);
```

While  `ToolItem` doesn't have API to add keylister, I add lister to `ToolBar`.

added code is

```
    toolBar.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        //@Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        //@Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT){
                clickedPrevious();  
                return;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT){
                clickedNext();
                return;
            }               
        }           
    });
```

This however does not work.

**How to add keyboard-lead actions to Eclipse Editor?**

Comment: In plugins you usually use key bindings (`org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point) for commands to set up keys.

Comment: Yes, but that would require to define Actions, that I am not good at. I thought I could do without that.

Comment: Actually was looking at https://github.com/culmat/eExplorer/blob/master/com.github.culmat.eexplorer.plugin/src/com/github/culmat/eexplorer/views/ExplorerView.java example